# Can we install ROS-Indigo from cd or usb?

Tags: usb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a system without an option to connect to the internet. Is there any way to install ROS from a CD or pendrive?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190692/can-we-install-ros-indigo-from-cd-or-usb?/) by [robospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/18911/robospace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use this command to download the .deb package:

> sudo apt-get -d install "package"

And then, you should found this package in:
"/var/cache/apt/archives/"

Now you can install the package with:

> sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb

---

Originally posted by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) with karma: 131 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/18911/robospace/) on 2014-08-23**:
Thanks for the answer. I have installed the ROS hydro using the command `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full` and  i have a lot of ros related .deb files in :"/var/cache/apt/archives/". Does the `-d` option in `sudo apt-get -d install "package"` makes it as a single .deb file?

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-08-23**:
Maybe this can help you
http://askubuntu.com/questions/59094/create-final-deb-file-from-multiple-deb-files